# Blazor Wasm components not rendering

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using latest MudBlazor with .net 7. Everything seems to work, but for some reason I cannot get components to render. Pages work fine. If I do the component inside the page itself it works fine.

Example: On Main layout I have this line for a drawer.

```
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" Elevation="1" Class="mud-theme-primary">
  <MudDrawerHeader>
     <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Inexl</MudText>
</MudDrawerHeader>
   <NavMenu></NavMenu>
</MudDrawer>
```

NavMenu is a simple Component Containing the following:

```
<MudNavMenu>
  <MudNavLink Href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Home">Home</MudNavLink>
</MudNavMenu>
```

It will not show up. I've tried moving it and replacing that information with text and it will not render. I've tried multiple components in different pages. Not sure what else to try.

If I paste the content of the component inside the page, it renders fine. I've tried it on 2 different machines thinking it may be a caching issue.

When I inspect the page, the component just shows up as `<navmenu></navmenu>`

### **Update**

Created a Blank default project from Visual Studio. Even the 'Counter' and basic components do not load on the sample without making any changes...

I've created 2 new projects with different naming styles.

My.Sample.App - Doesn't work

App - Works.

Not sure why this is.

### ** Fixed **

So it seems it was something to do with namespacing.

I had my projects formatted into This.Is.Project format.

I changed all projects to use This.Project format and suddenly everything worked. Not sure why the 3 dot format causes issues.

Comment: Right-click in your browser window, click "inspect."  Open the console window.  See if you have any errors.  You can also look for errors in the Output window of Visual Studio.

Comment: Somehow it seems to be naming related. I've created a few test projects inside my solution, and one one works. I'm not sure why, but if I name it 'App' , it works great. If I name it something like 'My.Application.UI' it fails.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems it was something to do with namespacing.

I had my projects formatted into 'This.Is.Project' format.

I changed all projects to use 'This.Project' format and suddenly everything worked. Not sure why the 3 dot format causes issues.

Comment: As a practical matter, I've gotten into the habit of declaring a namespace in every razor file I write.  The namespace of a razor file is inferred from the folder the file is in if you don't declare one, but if you move the razor file or change the inferred namespace somewhere else, weird things happen.  I don't like "hidden" functionality, so I make the namespace declaration explicit.